# Can't color java SWT button

Tags: java, button, colors, swt

I saw in many forums that it is not possible to color an **SWT** button.

I'm developing an RCP application under **Eclipse** and **win32**.

Here is my color code :

```
 Button stop=new Button(uploadInformationTab, SWT.PUSH);
 Display display=Display.getCurrent();
 Color red=display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
 stop.setBackground(red);
```

And it's not setting the background to red.

So, why it's not possible ? Is there a solution ?

Thks

Ismail

Comment: Useful link, thank you greg